# Rename Sencha touch 2 project without rebuilding native packager

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd, phonegap-cli, phonegap

I have existing project on `Sencha touch 2`. Now I want to change application name. As packager I use `phonegap`. Is there any way to change app name without rebuilding all phonegap project (plugins etc)?